# "Горючьми слезами заливалася"

Tags: орфография, литература, история

В "Песне про царя Ивана Васильевича, молодого опричника и удалого купца Калашникова" М. Ю. Лермонтова есть строфа:

> Говорила так Алена Дмитревна,
>   **Горючьми** слезами заливалася.

Что это за форма -- *горючьми*? Почему после *ч* стоит мягкий знак?

Answer (score 1):

Это, скорее всего, **старая форма окончания ЬМИ** (вместо ИМИ) по аналогии с окончаниями существительных в Т.п.: плетьми, костьми, лошадьми.

Также: Александр Островский, Том 3. Пьесы 1862-1864. Явление пятое. ... Не скажет; нет, не скажет, промолчит, Махнет рукой, а иногда заплачет, Так и уйдет. Посмотришь вслед ему, Да и зальешься **горючьми слезами.**

Answer (score 0):

Это застывшее сочетание, восходит к творительному падежу сочетания "горючи слёзы" (прилагательное - в краткой форме). В древнерусском краткие прилагательные склонялись, формы косвенных падежей кратких прилагательных были похожи на формы полных, но как бы "стянуты".

Вот примерная табличка кратких форм церковнославянского, если хотите более подробно. 
[Грамматика старославянского языка / Имена прилагательные | sovershenstvo-mysli.ru](http://www.sovershenstvo-mysli.ru/pismennost/grammatika-staroslavyanskogo-yazyka-imena-prilagatelnye.html)

Правда, здесь непросто разобраться, надо учитывать, что церковнославянский и древнерусский находились в сложных взаимоотношениях, то, сходя, то расходясь едва ли не до времен Ломоносова (в ломоносовской грамматике еще ощущается влияние старославянского), да и старославянский и церковнославянский - тоже не совсем тождественны.